# Android drag event not working on 4.4.2 with ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been implementing an Ionic app in AngularJS.

I have a list of 'cards' one on top of the other in a vertical fashion. The user can scroll to see more cards, or swipe them off the screen. This is fine on IOS (tested on the 5c and the 4) but on the HTC One M8 (Android) there is a bug, which doesn't allow user to swipe/drag an element.

I have seen this bug documented here:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1129
and 
http://uihacker.blogspot.tw/2011/01/android-touchmove-event-bug.html

However when I try to implement a solution such as the one offered in the latter link my app crashes.

My gesture handle events:

```
var self = this;

  ionic.onGesture('dragstart', function(e) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      self._doDragStart(e)
    });

  }, this.elemToDrag);

  ionic.onGesture('drag', function(e) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { 
      self._doDrag(e)
    });
  }, this.elemToDrag);

  ionic.onGesture('dragend', function(e) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { 
    self._doDragEnd(e); 
  });
  }, this.elemToDrag);
},

_doDragStart: function(e) {
},

_doDrag: function(e) {
    //handle dragging
},

_doDragEnd: function(e) {
  this.transitionOut(e);
}
```

I have tried adding e.preventDefault() to the events but it seems to do nothing. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you post the corresponding dom for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to replicate the same code but using `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` as your events and as you mentioned in the bug link, preventing `touchstart` with `preventDefault()`.

Alternative will be to replicate it with `mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseup` but detecting the device as in IOS will bring undesired side effects.

I mean you use the IONIC way in the devices that works and manually replicate the behaviour outside IONIC for those who doesnt. Ive been checking, seems there is no workaround yet.

Comment: Appreciate the effort Ill have a go and will mark this as correct if any work, had to do something else and had ten mins to give the bounty! dont spend it all at once

Answer (score 0):

This started working on Android when I started using iScroll-probe to take over the scrolling. I also used transforms for scrolling instead of native scroll.

Hope this helps